# React Material UI - How to get the width / height of parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, size, material-ui

I am using [React Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) with react router and I would like to get the height / width of the parent component ( so that I can set up the ideal size ).

A picture is better than 1000 words :
[image]

My component :

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Player(props) {
    const { playlistId } = useParams();
    const YOUTUBE_BASE_PLAYLIST_LINK = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=";

    // how to get them ?
    const heigth = "320px";
    const width = "640px";

    return (
        <ReactPlayer
            controls={true}
            url={YOUTUBE_BASE_PLAYLIST_LINK + playlistId}
            playing={true}
            width={width}
            height={heigth}
        />
    )
}
```

My router:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import Player from "./components/PlaylistPlayer/Player";
import {Container} from "@material-ui/core";
import basicStyle from "./components/Home/styles"

function Root({ store }) {

    const classes = basicStyle();

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    render={(props) => <Home {...props} classes={classes} />}
                />
                <main className={classes.content}>
                    <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                    <Container>
                        <Route path="/playlists/:playlistId" component={Player} />
                    </Container>
                </main>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default Root
```

What is the best/clean way to achieve my objective ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player#responsive-player it seems you can have a responsive player so it fits your parent container.

Comment: Yes and I got something like that ^^ ( ok for width , not for the height )
https://imgur.com/ozpPG9t 

EDIT: Oups, I forgot to add the css - will retry ...

Comment: Check on the parent's height. You could try setting it to 100vh or saying it's a 100% so its child (the video) fits that height.

Comment: Thanks It works : I was curious to find out if it was programmatically to know that without create the div

Comment: In React, there's a way to get the height/width of an element using refs too, it's a little bit tricky sometimes but it can be really helpful when you're trying to handle the DOM for animations or stuff that are merely related to the UI/UX. You can read a little bit more about refs in here: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I discovered that in the docs of Material UI : https://material-ui.com/system/sizing/ ... but it seems nobody documented how to properly use that ( "import { sizing } from '@material-ui/system';")